# Associate Subscription model with User model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-ipn, stripe-payments, paypal-subscriptions

I have Stripe and PayPal setup on the subscription model. I need help understanding how to create the association between the subscription and the users model.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Subscription model:

```
    belongs_to :plan
      validates_presence_of :plan_id
      validates_presence_of :email

      attr_accessor :stripe_card_token, :paypal_payment_token

      def save_with_payment
        if valid?
          if paypal_payment_token.present?
            save_with_paypal_payment
          else
            save_with_stripe_payment
          end
        end
      end

      def paypal
        PaypalPayment.new(self)
      end

      def save_with_paypal_payment
        response = paypal.make_recurring
        self.paypal_recurring_profile_token = response.profile_id
        save!
      end

      def save_with_stripe_payment
        customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, card: stripe_card_token)
        self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
        save!
      rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
        logger.error "Stripe error while creating customer: #{e.message}"
        errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit card."
        false
      end

      def payment_provided?
        stripe_card_token.present? || paypal_payment_token.present?
      end

  def cancel_recurring
     response = ppr.cancel_subscription(at_date_end: true)
     self.current_date_end_at = Time.at(response.current_date_end)
     self.plan_id = plan.id
     self.status = "canceled"
     return self.save
   end
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably have a has_one -> belongs_to between users and subscriptions. The Subscription has many attributes that can change a lot over time and when designing anything one of the first questions you should ask is, "what is going to change over time?"

You could then make a `subscribed?` method on the user for syntactic sugar

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :subscription

  def subscribed?
    subscription.present?
  end
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

You'll want to have a column in your subscription table for `user_id` so you can use the association properly.

In addition, in the migration, you can add this column by using `belongs_to` (if you're on a newer version of Rails:

```
create_table :subscriptions do |t|
  t.belongs_to :user
  t.string :account_id
  t.timestamps
end
```

If you have everything set up right, then this should work in the `rails console`:

```
User.first.subscription # => Subscription<>
Subscription.first.user # => User <>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am clear on how to add the relationship between the models. The part I need help understanding is how to create the action. For example when user pays and the Subscription table is updated with the token and email, how can I update the Users table from it to show that user id 12 is now subscribed to plan 1. Setting the Subscription model to belongs_to is the first small step, which is why I know how to do that part haha.

Comment: As long as you have a `_id` column in the belongs_to table, Rails should fill it in for you. In your case, adding a `user_id` to the subscription table.

Comment: Wait, maybe I'm misunderstanding your setup a little. So you have a plan, a subscription, and a User. A user has one subscription, and a subscription will point to a plan, yeah? Also, Do you want to delete/update the subscription or do you want a new record each time it changes (for historical purposes)?

Comment: Yes. I have a Plans table (includes id, name, price, length). There's a Subscription table (includes plan_id, email, stripe_customer_token, and two PayPal tokens for customer and recurring profile). To the second question, I think it's best if user can update/delete subscription. If the second option was present I'm not sure about the structure of it with one user potentially having two subscriptions listed in the database. So I think the safest route would be to delete/update. Do you need me to add back original code?

Comment: It's fine, I was just making sure I wasn't making assumptions and leading you in the wrong direction. I updated my answer. Is it more helpful to you or at least more applicable to your situation if you've already figured it out?

Comment: Thanks I was able to get it setup. Starting to create code now that will allow user to change their subscription. Thanks for assistance